# <meter> Color Change on Animation Health Bar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm making a health bar and I wish to use `<meter>`. I have it working except it doesn't change color as it decreases. I figured I could fix this with an `if` tree but I don't know how to change the color of the bar when it hits a particular width. Any ideas? Thanks!!

FIDDLE:
http://jsfiddle.net/Thaikhan/d018xzbj/13/

HTML:

```
<meter id="your_meter" min="0" low="30" optimum="100" high="50" max="100" value="80">   </meter>
<input type="submit" id="byBtn" value="Change" onclick="change()"/>
```

JavaScript:

```
function change(){
setTimeout(function () {
    var start = $('#your_meter').attr('value');
    var end = 55;
    if (start > 50) {
        //STARTING FROM GREEN
        if (end < 50) {
            //CONTINUE PAST GREEN
            var css = document.createElement("style");
            css.type = "text/css";
            css.innerHTML = "#your_meter::-webkit-meter-optimum-value { transition: width 3s; width: 50% !important; }";
            document.body.appendChild(css);
            //CHANGE COLOR AND CONTINUE TO DECREASE///??????????????????
                if (end < 30) {
                    //CONTINUE PAST YELLOW
                }
                else {
                //STOP BEFORE YELLOW ENDS
                setTimeout(function() {
                    var css2 = document.createElement("style");
                    css2.type = "text/css";
                    css2.innerHTML = "#your_meter::-webkit-meter-optimum-value { transition: width 3s; width: "+end+"% !important; }";
                    document.body.appendChild(css2);   
                }, 3000);
            }
        }
        else {
            //STOP BEFORE GREEN ENDS
            var css = document.createElement("style");
            css.type = "text/css";
            css.innerHTML = "#your_meter::-webkit-meter-optimum-value { transition: width 3s; width: "+end+"% !important; }";
            document.body.appendChild(css);
        }
    }...
```

Comment: Doesn't work at all in Firefox 31.0

Comment: Well that's good to know. I've been using Chrome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is because whilst you are updating the meter optimum value through CSS, you are not updating the value that the meter is actually using.

You will need to dynamically update the value of the meter's value, whilst you're updating the CSS value. You can do it like this:

```
document.getElementById("your_meter").value = "30";
```

So, to do what you're trying to do would look something like this:

```
function change(){
    var end = 35;
    var meter = document.getElementById("your_meter");
    var current = meter.value;

    function render(){
        console.log(meter.value);

        if(current <= end){
            window.cancelAnimationFrame(render);
            return;
        }

        meter.value = current - 1;

        current = meter.value;

        window.requestAnimationFrame(render);
    }

    window.requestAnimationFrame(render);
    render();
}
```

Based on a dynamic time:

```
function change(){
    var end = 35;
    var meter = document.getElementById("your_meter");
    var current = meter.value;
    var interval;
    var speed = 30;

    function render(){
        console.log(meter.value);

        if(current <= end){
            clearInterval(interval);
            return;
        }

        meter.value = current - 1;

        current = meter.value;

        window.requestAnimationFrame(render);
    }

    interval = setInterval(render, speed);
}
```

Comment: Note that this also fixes most of your cross browser issues.

Comment: Thank you so much Kevin! I do have one more question though. How can I control the rate of decrease?

Comment: If you don't want it to be every frame, change window.requestAnimationFrame to setInterval and give it a value. I'll update.

Comment: One last thing. The speed interval adds a delay equivalent to the value. This is apparent at speed = 5000. Is there an easy way to avoid the delay? Thank you again!

Comment: Also I'm not quite sure why but there doesn't seem to be a bit difference in rate of decrease between large numbers like 5k, 10k, 20k, etc. other than the delay.

Comment: I realized that if I just take your first script and change `- 1` to minus some fractional multiple of one, I could slow it down. Thank you kindly once more : )